# How do you ignore or skip certain characters in an array and store the rest of the array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, indexing, token, strtok

Basically, the user should input integers separated by commas. The integers then should be saved into another array. So let's say user inputs: "1,20,31,42" what should be done is 1 is saved in array[0] then 20 stored in array[1] etc. But somehow my code below just crashes when after I input the integers. How can I fix this? Also, what if the user enters "1, 20, 31, 42"? How do I ignore commas and spaces? Can strtok have more than one delimiter in it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void){
    // save input into a string
    char str[100];
    int coefficients[101], j;
    printf("enter number sep by commas: ");
    scanf("%99[^\n]", str);

    // get the first number (token)
    char* token;
    token = strtok(str, ",");
    int i;
    while (token != NULL){
        // convert the number into an integer (since its initially a char)
        i = atoi(token);

        // I want to store i in another array
        i = coefficients[j++];

        // get next number after the comma
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    printf("%d", coefficients[0]);
}
```

Comment: You probably want `fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin)` instead of `scanf("%s", str)`, because the `%s` format reads words and will stop reading when it encounters a space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of the lack of debugging diligence by OP, (ie. likely none done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** `j` is uninitialized in your program .

```
int coefficients[101], j;
```

Initialize it to `0` before using it here -

```
i = coefficients[j++];
```

**2.** And the above expression will assign value of `coefficients` to `i` (coefficients is also *uninitialized* ) . Write like this -

```
coefficients[j++]=i;
```

**3.** You print `int` variable with `%c` specifier , thus passing wrong argument invoking UB, here-

```
printf("%c", coefficients[0]);    
 /*     ^  use %d to print it */
```

> Also, what if the user enters "1, 20, 31, 42"?

To take input with space you can write `scanf` like this -

```
scanf("%99[^\n]", str);   // will read 99 characters until \n is encountered
```

[Click here to see demo.](https://ideone.com/8cWAdN)

Comment: Questions with bugs due to blatant uninitialized vars, like this one, get a down/close vote from me for gross negligence, (obviously, no debugging done).

Comment: @MartinJames I am so sorry okay, I'm new to coding so of course I don't know the stuff I'm missing....